# mysql :How to select two different column values from a single table using two different values of another table

Tags: mysql

My goal is to select two different values,say c & d from table2 using the fields  a and b of table1 in a single query.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Would help if you put up the sample table structure and data with expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT table2.c, table2.d
FROM table2
JOIN table1 ON table2.some_common_field = table1.other_common_field
WHERE (table1.a = XXX) AND (table1.b = YYY)
```